# Low level WCF exceptions as FaultException

Tags: c#, wcf

When i called my WCF service using an invalid action request i got an exception.I need to send this exception as a FaultException.

I tried out following scenarios:-

- I used `IErrorHandler` but `ProvideFault` function is not hitting for this service call(In other cases it is working fine).
- I have also used message inspector to handle the exception.But `AfterReceiveRequest` and `BeforeSendReply` are also not hitting during this call.

  How can i send all type of exception as FaultException

### **Request to service**

**Request:**
  POST /0710 HTTP/1.1

**Headers:**
  Connection: close
  Content-Length: 11
  Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="Invalid:S.O.A.P.:Action..."
  Host: userpc:9001

**Body:**

### Exception occured(From trace log)

**Exception Type**

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

**Message**

Unrecognized message version.

**Stack trace**

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.ContinueReading(Int32 bytesRead)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.DecodeBufferedMessageAsync()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.BeginParse()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult..ctor(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, HttpInput httpInput, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.BeginParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.BeginParseIncomingMessage(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginParseIncomingMessage(AsyncCallback asynCallback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1..ctor(HttpRequestContext requestContext, Action acceptorCallback, HttpChannelListener`1 listener, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.EnqueueContext(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(ListenerAsyncResult asyncResult, UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

*You can create similar situation by calling any WCF service using the below code*

```
public static string HttpPost(string URI)
        {
            try
            {
                var r = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(URI);
                r.Method = "POST";
                r.ContentType = @"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=""Invalid:S.O.A.P.:Action...""";                           
                var ws = new StreamWriter(r.GetRequestStream());
                ws.Write("<EmptyXml/>");
                ws.Close();
                var resp = (HttpWebResponse) r.GetResponse();
                var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                //I need to catch low level exception as Fault exception
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ex)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Where are you hosting your Service? WAS, IIS, WinService, WPF/Winforms? If it is WPF/Winforms you probably forgot to use (UseSynchronizationContext=False) in either your servicebehavior or your callbackbehavior.

Comment: I am using a WCF service library and it is launching from a WPF applicaton.And i am already using that attribute.The attributes that i am using int the service are  [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, ConfigurationName = "xxxxx",
        InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, Name = "xxxxx",
        Namespace = "xxxx.xx.xx", UseSynchronizationContext = false)]

Comment: Are u using callbacks somewhere?

Comment: I am not using callback in this service

Comment: Can you provide some more code on what you are trying?

Comment: Check the updated question for more details about the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with HttpWebRequest you will never receive a faultexception through the webrequest.

To get your faultexception you have to read it from the webexception response.

=>

```
try
        {
            var r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("/S");
            r.Method = "POST";
            r.ContentType = @"text/json; charset=utf-8; action=""Invalid:S.O.A.P.:Action...""";
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string postData = js.Serialize(new {something = "Hello World"});
            r.ContentLength = postData.Length;
            var ws = new StreamWriter(r.GetRequestStream());
            ws.Write(postData);
            ws.Close();
            var resp = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();

            var respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            if (respStream == null) return;
            var sr = new StreamReader(respStream);
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (stream == null) return;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
//At this point i'm just writing it to the console. However her you have your FaultException xml encoded.
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: When you run my sample code you will get a communication exception(Check service trace log). I need to send it as a FaultException.I am developing only the WCF service part.Client is developed by a third party vendor.Our service should pass a set of test cases provided by the client developers.One of that test case is provided in my question.We cannot change their test scenario.

Comment: And as stated you are getting your fault exception in the catch block, from there on you have to look into it what the reason is and where it happens, that way you will be able to catch it on the service side and generate your own faultexception.

Comment: FYI : My real issue is how to handle invalid action request and send it as FaultException from the WCF service.I am not worried about, how to handle that exception from the client.I provided that sample code to create similar error in the server side.

Comment: The message filters in WCF handle invalid messages for you as far as I know. And if they don't reach your server implementation they can't crash your server. Thus as far as I see it, it is handled. And on the client side they can also handle the return (as shown in the catch block) so I'm not really sure what else you want?